# Expand a python dictionary to express shared list values

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have the following simple dictionary in Python3.x:

```
example = {1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[7, 8, 9]}
```

I would like a way to expand the dictionary as follows:

```
expanded_example = {1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[7, 8, 9], 4:[5, 6], 5:[4, 6], 6:[4, 5], 7:[8, 9], 8:[7, 9], 9:[7, 8]}
```

This becomes quite complicated by values shared by multiple keys. As an example,

```
example2 = {1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[4, 7, 8, 9]}
```

Here 4 is a value in the lists associated with 1 and 2.

There are two approaches if there are "repeat" value elements:

(1) Only keep values immediately associated with a certain key:

```
{1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[4, 7, 8, 9], 4:[5, 6], 5:[4, 6], 6:[4, 5], 7:[8, 9], 8:[7, 9], 9:[7, 8]}
```

(2) Keep all associated values (as '4' is shared between keys '1' and '2'):

```
{1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[4, 7, 8, 9], 4:[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5:[4, 6], 6:[4, 5], 7:[4, 8, 9], 8:[4, 7, 9], 9:[4, 7, 8]}
```

EDITED:

My thought for this task was to use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict1 = {1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[4, 7, 8, 9]}
d_dict = defaultdict(list)

for k,l in dict1.items():
    for v in l:
        d_dict[v].append(l)

print(d_dict)
## defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {4: [[4, 5, 6], [4, 7, 8, 9]], 5: [[4, 5, 6]], 6: [[4, 5, 6]], 7: [[4, 7, 8, 9]], 8: [[4, 7, 8, 9]], 9: [[4, 7, 8, 9]]})
```

This gets me some of the way, but there are repeat elements in lists of lists...

Comment: Which of the two repeat strategies do you want to use?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BlackThunder Sorry, I didn't include this to keep the question clean. See the edit. This is closer to the second approach.

Comment: @OliverRadini I would prefer both actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**strategy 2**

```
example2 = {1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[4, 7, 8, 9]}
output = {**example2}

for val in example2.values():
    for idx,v in enumerate(val):
        if v not in output:
            output[v] = val[0:idx]+val[idx+1:]
        else:
            output[v].extend(val[0:idx]+val[idx+1:])

print(output)
#{1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [4, 7, 8, 9], 4: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5: [4, 6], 6: [4, 5], 7: [4, 8, 9], 8: [4, 7, 9], 9: [4, 7, 8]}
```

**strategy 1**

```
import copy
example2 = {1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[4, 7, 8, 9]}
output = copy.deepcopy(example2)

for val in example2.values():
    for num in val:
        if num in output:
            val.remove(num)

    for idx,v in enumerate(val):
        output[v] = val[0:idx]+val[idx+1:]

print(output)
#{1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [4, 7, 8, 9], 4: [5, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [4, 5], 7: [8, 9], 8: [7, 9], 9: [7, 8]}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This answer only deals with Approach #1.

You can work with copies of your data, as you should not add/remove dictionary items while iterating a view:

```
d = {1:[4, 5, 6], 2:[7, 8, 9]}

for k, v in list(d.items()):
    for w in v:
        L = v.copy()
        d[L.pop(L.index(w))] = L

print(d)

{1: [4, 5, 6], 2: [7, 8, 9], 4: [5, 6], 5: [4, 6],
 6: [4, 5], 7: [8, 9], 8: [7, 9], 9: [7, 8]}
```

Comment: @jpp Sorry, I'm confused: where did I change the question?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, Oops, my mistake, you edited to include your attempt. I've only dealt with one part anyway. I suggest you try something similar for the second part.